# Implementing sharding with CUBRID DB

Tags: database, scalability, sharding, cubrid

Do you know how can I utilize CUBRID database sharding on Amazon EC2 or any other computer environment. I can't find any information of how it is doe on their website. (http://www.cubrid.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand sharding is still on their roadmap.

Current version is still 8.4.1 and the [same presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/cubrid/growing-in-the-wild-the-story-by-cubrid-database-developers) on slide 51 shows their plans for future releases.

Answer (score 2):

I am related with CUBRID project.

CUBRID SHARD, the native database sharding feature, has already been developed. It will be released as part of CUBRID 8.4.2 which is set to be announced in three weeks on June 8, 2012. The manual and examples will be published along with the official announcement. You may want to subscribe to [CUBRID official blog](http://www.cubrid.org/blog) to receive news.

Comment: Since CUBRID SHARD has been released, here is Slideshare which explains how to configure sharding with CUBRID: http://www.slideshare.net/cubrid/database-sharding-the-right-way-easy-reliable-and-open-source-highload-2012